# Problems with jQuerys keyup + counter

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a - concerning my opinion - really crazy problem. The logic seems to be quite easy : But it doesn't work :)

I've upped a little part of the script:

[jquery onkeyup event](http://photographic-eye.de/html.html)

The snippet is for a instant search suggest.

Please blur the input field, open the console (firebug) und press arrowUp and arrowDown.

You will see a variable at the console, which should add or remove every time you hit the arrowUp/Down key 1 point.

But if you "reverse" the direction (e.g. arrowDown -arrowDown -arrowDown - 
arrowUp) the counter seems that it doesn't work correctly.

```
var c = 0;
$('#h7_3').keypress(function(e) {

    console.log('--------');
    console.log('c = ' + c);
    console.log('Key: = ' + e.keyCode);
    console.log('--------');

    if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.which == 38){ //38 = arrowUp
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40 || e.which == 40) { //40 = arrowDown
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#h7_3').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.which == 38){ //38 = arrowUp
        c--;
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40 || e.which == 40) { //40 = arrowDown
        c++;
    }
});
```

I would be really happs about a few tips :-)

Greetings, Chris

Comment: I think the code is working correctly, the keypress event triggered before the key up event so in that case you find the incremented or decremented value in log.

Comment: [Maybe this will help you?](http://jsfiddle.net/HrJg9/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a ready() function, and since you are preventing default the latter function is'nt triggered. Also, jQuery normalizes e.which :

```
$(function() {
    var c = 0;
    $('#h7_3').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40) {
            c = e.which == 38 ? c-1 : c+1;
            console.log('--------');
            console.log('c = ' + c);
            console.log('Key: = ' + e.which);
            console.log('--------');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vSRY2/1/)